# LWJGL/Slick-Util render issue

Tags: java, lwjgl

I'm working on a game and I'm trying to draw our logo and when I draws it has a black border, here is some of the code (only for the logo render)

code to draw the logo in GuiLoading.java

```
    @override
    public void ex() throws IOException{
            GL11.glColor3f(255, 255, 255);
            drawRec(0, 0, Client.width, Client.height);

            Texture logo = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("misc/hslogo.png"));
            logo.bind();
            drawRecWithTexture(Client.width / 4 , Client.height / 4, Client.width / 4 + 400, Client.height / 4 + 356);
    }
```

and code for the 'drawRec' and 'drawRecWithTexture' voids

```
public void drawRecWithTexture(int i, int j, int k, int l)
{
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2i(i, j);
        GL11.glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2i(i, l);
        GL11.glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
        GL11.glVertex2i(k, l);
        GL11.glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
        GL11.glVertex2i(k, j);
    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}

public void drawRec(int i, int j, int k, int l)
{
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glVertex2i(i, j);
        GL11.glVertex2i(i, l);
        GL11.glVertex2i(k, l);
        GL11.glVertex2i(k, j);
    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}
```

and a image of the output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDMK6.png)

[image]

Comment: Are you saying it is ignoring the alhpa?

Comment: what do you mean 'alhpa'

Comment: Sorry, typo, alpha.. as in the alpha channel.

Comment: I don't know whats wrong and by the way this is the first time I have used OpenGL

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I know I have functioning code at home. But I believe you want to add:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Below

GL11.glColor3f(255, 255, 255);

Also if what you are doing it fully 2D check out the [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) library in it entirety makes life so much easier.

Comment: No it looks like you are using Slick-Util not the full slick library

Comment: any way I'm rendering with my own code, I'm not rendering with the Slick system

Comment: Fair do's, I went down that path once, great for learning a system. But soon learnt if it is provided then use it.

Comment: So, is there any why I can fix the prob?

Comment: I'm just going to start again

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken it's because the dimensions of the texture image are not powers of 2 (32, 64, 128 etc.) try using software such as Paint.net or Gimp to resize it.